# how to remove twitter javascript from wp_head() in wordpress blog?

Tags: wordpress, function, header

I am trying to remove the following from my header, which is generated by wp_head()

script type='text/javascript' src='http://platform.twitter.com/anywhere.js?id=vnvNHGURk301uf50n6PGA&v=1&ver=1'>/script

I checked my functions.php file, which is hard for me to understand.  However, I did not see a line that says "script type='text/javascript' src='http://platform.twitter.com/anywhere.js?id=vnvNHGURk301uf50n6PGA&v=1&ver=1'>/script."

Can someone please tell me what I should be looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you have a twitter plugin activated. Check your WP-Admin - Plugins page and see if you have one activated.